# How can I increase internal storage of a Bliss OS dual boot installation

Tags: android-x86

I installed Bliss Os 11.7 (Kernel 4.9) as a dual boot with Win 10. Everything great, but the 8 GB I assigned Bliss OS is not enough.

How can I increase the size of my bliss os image?